# Does it make sense to have multiple domains in an enterprise to support Development, Testing, and Production?

Tags: domain

Currently, the enterprise operates in a single domain.  Development and Testing occur in the same domain.  Does it make sense to create a separate domain for development and testing that mimics the production domain?

Comment: Define "domain".

Comment: @joeqwerty, I'm referring to a network domain.
domain:  A collection of computers or other networked resources.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it makes sense and is a common practice I have encountered in multiple organizations.

It helps in separation of production and development environments in particular when infrastructure as code is implemented. Further you need a dedicated domain name for development when you want to be able to test the configuration of proxy servers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes your can accomplish this configuration in dns server by creating various sub domain as per your company requirement this is on-going general practice on most of companies as I experienced.